# How to get controller scope from multi-level directives in AngularJS(without $parent)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I access controller scope from multi-level directives  in below structure:

I create a directive that has multi-level scopes inside its.

```
 1. Controller scope
 1.2. Directive1 scope(main directive)
 1.2.1. Directive2 scope
 1.2.1.1 Directive3 scope
```

I want to get the controller scope from directive 3.

please don't refer to $parent because the parent level it's not certain and a user may use this directive inside another directive.(see below codes)

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
   <custom-dir>
      <dir1>
         <dir2>
            <dir3>
            </dir3>
          </dir2>
       </dir1>
    <custom-dir>
</div>
```

The users create a function in the Test controller and the function will be called in my Directive 3 scope(how to get controller scope?).

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
     <dir1>
         <dir2>
             <dir3>
             </dir3>
         </dir2>
     </dir1>
</div>
```

**More details(please don't refer to syntax error):**

The controller is:

```
App.controller('ScopeController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $uibModal, $http, $filter, $cookieStore, Common, $cookies) {
    $scope.runTest = function () {
        return `<input type='button' ng-click='testHtml()' value='Test'/>`;
    }
    $scope.testHtml = function () {
        alert("work");
    }
    $scope.model=someModel;
    $scope.config=someConfig;
    $scope.columns={html: $scope.runTest};
});
```

the dir1 directive:

```
App.directive("dir1", function ($compile, $filter, $rootScope, $timeout, Common, $window, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        priority: 1,
        terminal: false,
        templateUrl: "Content/html/Table.html?version=2.6",
        scope: {
            model: "=",
            columns: "=",
            config: "=",
            search: "@",
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.CallFunc = function (html) {
                if (typeof (html) =="function" )
                    return html();
                else {
                    return scope.$parent.$eval(html + "()", {});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

the dynamic directive compile the runTest output

```
App.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                ele.html(html);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

If I change the line `$compile(ele.contents())(scope);` to `$compile(ele.contents())(scope.$parent.$parent);` it's work.

In this directive, I need get the controller scope without $parent because
some users may use this directive inside another directive same below:

```
<custom-dir>
    <dir1 model="model" columns="columns" config="config">
        <div dynamic="CallFunc(columns.html)"></div>
    </dir1>
</custom-dir>
```

The using HTML tag

```
<dir1 model="model" columns="columns" config="config">
    <div dynamic="CallFunc(columns.html)"></div>
</dir1>
```

Comment: Why you need to get scope, for visiting data you'd better using a service.

Comment: are u referring to the entire scope or just scope variables

Comment: @huan feng. for calling a user-defined method.

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka. scope functions and not variables

Comment: if you want to call controller function from a directive, use events

Comment: Dispatch an event, you can create a custom EventDispatch or you can use scope.$broadcast

Comment: Use services/factories they can be injected anywhere and are singletons, alternatively use events but be careful with use of events they are not generally as efficient and can end up in terrible event loops when they are used heavily for communication, instead can generally use singletons as communication bridges between components.

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka. the function is inside controller scope and in the directive scope, I can't call it.

Comment: sure u can. using an event u can communicate through different scopes.  check @huanfeng anwser

Comment: @huan feng. the $broadcast is a good solution but I want to get the controller scope.

Comment: what you mean scope? which scope you want to get? child scope? you want to get child scope in parent controller?

Comment: @huan feng. the controller scope in the dynamic directive.

Comment: @ImanBahrampour Why you need the scope? If you want to pass the data from child directive scope to parent scope, you can also pass it via $broadcast. Although i think it's better to use a service here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue handle with following codes:

A service for storing the controller scope:

```
App.service('TableService', function () {
        return {
            MyScope: null
        };
    });
```

Inject the TableService to dynamic directive(this directive compiles dynamic content):

```
App.directive('dynamic', function ($compile,TableService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                ele.html(html);
                $compile(ele.contents())(TableService.MyScope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And finally in the controller:

```
App.controller('ScopeController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $uibModal, 
              $http, $filter, $cookieStore, Common, $cookies,TableService) {
    TableService.myScope = $scope;        
    $scope.runTest = function () {
        return `<input type='button' ng-click='testHtml()' value='Test'/>`;
    }
    $scope.testHtml = function () {
        alert("work");
    }
    $scope.model=someModel;
    $scope.config=someConfig;
    $scope.columns={html: $scope.runTest};
});
```

After that, the dynamic directive can access controller scope and all dynamic events(like testHtml) will be called even if the directive put in another directive(without using the $parent).

thank you [@shaunhusain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509344/shaunhusain), [huan feng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943632/huan-feng) for giving me an idea.

Comment: No problem on the ideas, glad you took it in your own hands here.  One thing to note it's ideal if you just pass along the function to call to the service or whatever it needs a minimum to do the work so it doesn't need to have access to the whole scope object (will make testing the thing easier if the interface or things it needs setup are smaller)  In your particular case using the scope for compiling it may be the only way but I'm not entirely clear on the original use case for the directives so can't say entirely.

Comment: @shaunhusain. the main issue was that I didn't know which functions the user use in dynamic content(in the runTest  function) and I must handle all functions.

Answer (score 1):

In child controller do something like:

```
$scope.$broadcast('yourEvent');
```

In parent controller do the listener:

```
$scope.$on('yourEvent' , function(){
    //Handle your logic            
});
```

Comment: Not that it can't happen with a service but it's easier to trace down when you end up with a loop where say "yourEvent" might end up dispatching another event to get another component to do something.  Chasing down the source of events (async) is much harder than a direct synchronous call that shows up in the stacktrace.  Not saying there is no place for events but use this with caution and consciously.

Comment: the broadcast is a good solution but is there a way to get the controller scope?. please consider added details

Comment: @huan feng. when you broadcast an event in child controller, then you can't access it in parent controller. for this purpose, you must emit your function in child controller and then get it in parent controller.

Answer (score 1):

A special case service

```
.service('DirectDispatcher', function(){
  return {
    fireMe: angular.noop
  }
});
```

First directive registers a function callback

```
.directive(
...
  link:function(DirectDispatcher){
    function myHandler() {window.alert('just testing')}
    DirectDispatcher.fireMe = myHandler;
  }
```

...
);

Second directive fires the function callback

```
.directive(
...
  link:function(DirectDispatcher){
    DirectDispatcher.fireMe();
  }

...
);
```

Comment: please consider added details. maybe it can help.