# How to communicate events between sibling component directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

### angular JS $watch and communication between two directives

I Have a code in AngularJs where I'd like to call function in one directive when state of variable changes in other directive. I have a controller:

```
app.controller('TaskerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.tasksReload = false;        
    }
]);
```

Here as we can see is variable **tasksReload**. I'd like to call function in one of my directive when state of that variable changes on true in other directive. 
 Below I show code of my directives:

```
app.directive('newTaskWidget', function (TaskerForm, Consultants) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    sortReverse: '=sortReverse',
                    tasksReload: '=tasksReload'
                },
       scope.test = function(){
                    scope.tasksReload = true;
       }

app.directive('taskListWidget', function ($filter, $uibModal, Notification, TaskerForm, Consultants) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            sortReverse: '=sortReverse',
            departments: '=departmtens',
            myDepartment: '=myDepartment',
            tasksReload: '=tasksReload'
        },
        link: function (scope) {

            scope.$watch('tasksReload', function (data) {

                console.log("Musze przeladowac taski");
            });
```

Below I show HTML code with my directives:

```
<new-task-widget sort-reverse="false" tasks-reload = 'tasksReload'>
</new-task-widget>

<task_list_widget sort-reverse="false" departmtens = "departments"
    my-department="session.user.department" tasks-reload = 'tasksReload'>
</task_list_widget>
```

As we can see in **newTaskWidget** there is a function `test`. I'd like to call **$watch** action in **taskListWidget** when value **scope.tasksReload = true;**  is been changed but it dosen't work correctly. I call that function with **ng-click** directive on button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary validateButton" ng-click="test()">

    </button>
```

There is no reaction. How could I do that properly? I would be grateful for help. Best regards ;)

Comment: You put restrict: 'E'  and using it as an attribute in your HTML. Did you miss to add anything ?

Comment: Go to this link:[get controller scope from multi-level directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558337/7487135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to communicating click events between sibling components is to use [`scope.$root.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast):

```
scope.$root.$broadcast("test-event",args);
```

And in the sibling component, use [`scope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on):

```
scope.$on("test-event", function(event,args) {
    //Handle event here
});
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xxBy8zDLGUBT5kdyqaqY?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive('newTaskWidget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { },
        template: `
          <fieldset>
            <button ng-click="test()">Click me</button>
          </fieldset>
        `,
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
            scope.test = function(){
                scope.$root.$broadcast("test-event");
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('taskListWidget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template: `<fieldset>clicks={{count}}</fieldset>`,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.count=0;
            scope.$on('test-event', function (event) {
                scope.count++;
                console.log("Musze przeladowac taski");
            });
        }
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <new-task-widget>
    </new-task-widget>

    <task_list_widget>
    </task_list_widget>
  </body>
```